# Moving only unread emails

Tags: vba, outlook

This script will move email from Joe Smith and Wally Gator to the _ALERTS mail box.

It is slow. I think it reads through the whole inbox (which is huge).

Would there be a way to click on the "Unread" filter in Outlook and have the script look at unread emails?

```
Sub MoveItems()
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItem As Object

Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myItems = myInbox.Items
Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("_ALERTS")
Dim varSearchTerm As Variant: For Each varSearchTerm In Array("Joe Smith", "Wally Gator")
Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = '" & varSearchTerm & "'")
    While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        myItem.Move myDestFolder
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
    Wend
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the filter item `[UNREAD] = {TRUE/FALSE}`

```
Sub MoveItems()
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItem As Object

Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myItems = myInbox.Items
Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("_ALERTS")
Dim varSearchTerm As Variant: For Each varSearchTerm In Array("Joe Smith", "Wally Gator")
Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = '" & varSearchTerm & "' AND [UNREAD] = TRUE")
    While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        myItem.Move myDestFolder
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
    Wend
Next
End Sub
```